# EntityFramework Core including multilevel navigation properties in results

Tags: entity-framework-core

In EF Core, we can use `.Include` and `.ThenInclude` methods to load related data in queries. Let's take the example from the official documentation:

```
1. using (var context = new BloggingContext())
2. {
3.     var blogs = context.Blogs
4.         .Include(blog => blog.Posts)
5.            .ThenInclude(post => post.Author)
6.            .ThenInclude(author => author.Photo)
7.         .Include(blog => blog.Owner)
8.            .ThenInclude(owner => owner.Photo)
9.         .ToList();
10.}
```

In the example above, it included the `Post.Author` property and then the `Author.Photo` property using `ThenInclude` in lines 5 and 6.

But what if the `Post` entity has another navigation property that I want to include? If I use `ThenInclude` after line 6, it will be relative to the `Photo` property and if I use `Include` it will be relative back to the `Blogs` property. Is there any way to solve this directly in the query statement?

Comment: I always just `.Include(x => x.SomeProperty.PropertyA).Include(x => x.SomeProperty.PropertyB).Include(x => x.SomeCollection.Select(y => y.PropertyC))` etc (but not sure that's allowed in Core, it is in 6x)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can repeat identical `Include`s as often as you like (and deem sensible):

```
 var blogs = context.Blogs
     .Include(blog => blog.Posts)
        .ThenInclude(post => post.Author)
        .ThenInclude(author => author.Photo)
     .Include(blog => blog.Posts)
        .ThenInclude(post => post.Document)
     .Include(blog => blog.Posts)
        .ThenInclude(post => post. ...)
```